# How to delete hidden excel cells in through VBScript?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm having a problem with an excel dictionary that have hidden cells and it is giving me headches to clean it. So I got this code in VBA. But I want it in VBScript so I can execute it straight from Stata with no need of opening the sheet to delete the cells

the code in VBA:

```
Sub exclui_celulas_ocultas()

Dim lastRow
lastRow = 1000
    For iCntr = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Rows(iCntr).Hidden = True Then Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Also I'd like to make the "lastRow" generic, instead of specifying a constant.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/62576

Comment: you should def post any VBScript you've tried so far

Comment: Please make sure you actually pose a question

Comment: Thanks Ken White
I edited it now, Geert. Thanks